# Is there documentation anyplace for adding weather to PostGIS/Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, weather

We have an internal PostGIS/Geoserver for rendering map tiles for the world based on OpenStreetMaps.  We would like to overlay weather, but would like to do so without referencing external URLs.  The weather data at this URL (http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/NCR/) uses a gif/gfw format, but I am so new to GIS that I am not familiar with how I can take advantage of these for our use.

Does anyone know of any documentation on how to get weather layers in PostGIS/Geoserver, or even better, using the gif/gfw format from above?

Comment: for historical data yes, for up-to-the-minute no, with MaryBeth a webservice would be a better way to do this.

Comment: do you have your own weather station?

Comment: There is lots computations for Weather see the Weather Research and Forecasting Model WRF http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/model.html for an understanding

Comment: No, we do not have our own weather station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid external urls in your map application you could use geoserver to cascade the external weather maps to your app, then you can use your cache etc.

Comment: I did not know about this, I will look in to it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using a gif for weather data--as that would be a static file and you would have to update your gif constantly. A webservice would be a much better choice to dynamically display data.

NOAA and NWS both have data sets for this.